# Django migration can't find GDALRaster

Tags: python, django, gdal

I took over a project with Django, Django REST framework and Leaflet to store drawn path in a database. Installing Django in an `virtualenv` and trying to migrate it raises:

> File "D:\SHK\ElektroClean\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\operations.py", line 7, in 
>       from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALRaster
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'GDALRaster'

In the directory `D:\SHK\ElektroClean\py27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal` is a folder called raster. Is renaiming this folder to GDALRaster the fix?

Anyone suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Which Django version are you using? Is the [`gdal`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) package installed properly inside the virtualenv? What's the value of `django.contrib.gis.gdal.HAS_GDAL`? Try `import django.contrib.gis.gdal.raster.source.GDALRaster` and see if that gives you an error message.

Comment: Im using Django 1.10

Comment: And the GDAL import is working properly? The flag is only set, when the library could be imported.

Comment: the import says:
django.contrib.gis.gdal.error.GDALException: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal111", "gdal110", "gdal19", "gdal18", "gdal17"). Try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings

Comment: Well, looks like the gdal module isn't properly installed. Try with `pip install gdal` (inside the virtualenv!) or, if that doesn't work, have a look at [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip).

Comment: Thanks for the link but its not helping...

Building on Windows with Python 2.7.10

Comment: Just Changing the Name of the raster Folder in D:\SHK\ElektroClean\py27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal
to GDALRaster let the migration work and the runserver too.

Comment: Yeah, but that won't survive a package update ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

solved did mistakes on installing GDAL -.-

On Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
pip install gdal
```

On Windows install GDAL Core and GDAL Python bindings from gisinternals

Comment: sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev worked for me. Thanks Trevirius!